# A '*' argument results in "value too great for base" error

Tags: bash, command-line-arguments

I was making this really simple arithmetic script but got this odd error when I try to pass an `*` operator. 
Syntax: [command] [num1] [num2] [arithmetic operator]
Here is the code:

```
result=$(($1$3$2))
echo "Calculation result is: $result "
```

Passing a '*' operator like this:

```
bash my_script.sh 1 2 *
```

... returns the following error:

> line 7: 3Access: value too great for base (error token is "3Access")

I botched together a fix for it by replacing `*` with `\\\*` through a test statement. Though I would like to understand **why** this error occurs.

The only threads I found refer to the error regarding above-octal values being assumed by BASH to be octal. But it's unclear to me why `*` is being looked at as a numerical value at all.

Comment: could reproduce with `echo "$((3Access))"`, by default base is 10 and alpha characters are to great in base 10, however in base 36 it's working `echo "$((36#3Access))"` but may be not what you want, the reason why it's looked as a numerical value is that double parenthesis are used for arithmetic expansion

Comment: You haven't shared the exact command but I presume you aren't quoting `*` properly thus the shell expands it.

Comment: How do you "pass an *"? Do you run `cmd 4 5 *`? Or do you escape the asterisk?

Comment: Can you please provide the output of `echo $1`, `echo $2`, `echo $3`. You are also increasing your chances of getting help significantly by providing code that allows others to reproduce the problem. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `*` has a special meaning in the shell language. It is used by filename expansion and expands to all non hidden files and folders in the current directory and passes them as individual arguments to the script.

Just try this script to see:

```
#!/bin/bash
# star.sh
echo "$1"
echo "$2"
echo "$3"
# and so on ...
```

Now run it:

```
bash star.sh *
```

It will print the first 3 files in your current directory.

---

To avoid filename expansion to happen you need to quote the `*`. Like this:

```
bash your_script.sh 1 2 '*'
```

or escape it

```
bash your_script.sh 1 2 \*
```

See [Bash Manual: Filename Expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Filename-Expansion.html).

Comment: I wasn't properly escaping it, yes. thank you for the response.